# CSS reset for plugin’s front end?

Tags: plugins

Is there a best practice of implementing resets for front-end code? In back-end I can assume WP will handle reset itself, but I can’t be sure that front-end theme will have a reset (most likely it will).

How would one approach this? I don’t want to add a full reset for just one section, but I also don’t want to style for inconsistencies which should be done with reset.

Comment: what exactly do you mean in "reset"

Comment: @MarkKaplun Something like `normalize.css`

Comment: why would you want to do that? you styling should blend with the theme, not "nullify" it

Comment: Maybe your don't have the good approach. Plugins are designed to handle data and themes manage apparence of the frontoffice.

Comment: @mmm If I’m adding a complex gallery layout, how can I be sure theme will manage its appearance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a plugin your styling should blend with the styling of the theme and not override it, therefor style "reset" is just not something you should do. On the contrary, it is better to have an option in your plugin to emit just HTML with no styling at all as it is hard to style anything in a way which will look good on all themes.